# Django not able to see data from the model on web page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to build a project management system but I am not able to see the data from the models on the web page. My code is below. Also, I am not sure if the data is getting stored in the database at all.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "Admin"), (2, "Staff"), (3, "Client"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)
    
    
class AdminUser(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Staffs(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage #To upload Profile Picture
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core import serializers
import json

from powercons_app.models import CustomUser, AdminUser, Staffs, Projects, Tasks, Clients, Contracts
from .forms import AddClientForm, EditClientForm

def add_staff(request):
    return render(request, "admintemplate/add_staff_template.html")


def add_staff_save(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        messages.error(request, "Invalid Method ")
        return redirect('add_staff')
    else:
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')

        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, user_type=2)
            user.staffs.phone = phone
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "Staff Added Successfully!")
            return redirect('add_staff')
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Add Staff!")
            return redirect('add_staff')



def manage_staff(request):
    staffs = Staffs.objects.all()
    context = {
        "staffs": staffs
    }
    return render(request, "admintemplate/manage_staff_template.html", context)
```

templates

```
add staff template

{% extends 'admintemplate/base_template.html' %}

{% block page_title %}
    Add Staff
{% endblock page_title %}

{% block main_content %}

{% load static %}

<section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- general form elements -->
                    <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Add Staff</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->
                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_staff_save' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        
                                {% comment %} Display Messages {% endcomment %}
                                {% if messages %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    {% if message.tags == "error" %}
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        {{ message }}
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% elif message.tags == "success" %}
                                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        {{ message }}
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="id_email">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="id_username">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Phone</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="phone"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            


                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->

                        <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Staff</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->

                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </section>

  {% endblock main_content %}
```

manage staff template - the one where data should show

```
{% extends 'admintemplate/base_template.html' %}

{% block page_title %}
    Manage Staff
{% endblock page_title %}

{% block main_content %}

{% load static %}

<section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'add_staff' %}" role="button">+ Add Staff</a> <br/>&nbsp;

            {% if messages %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    {% if message.tags == "error" %}
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        {{ message }}
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% elif message.tags == "success" %}
                                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                        {{ message }}
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                </div>
            {% endif %}
                                

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- general form elements -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Staff Details</h3>

                            <div class="card-tools">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                                <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search">

                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Last Login</th>
                                <th>Date Joined</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for staff in staffs %}
                                <tr>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.phone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.last_login }}</td>
                                <td>{{ staff.admin.date_joined }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{% url 'edit_staff' staff.admin.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a> 
                                    <a href="{% url 'delete_staff' staff.admin.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                        </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->

                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </section>

  {% endblock main_content %}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful for my project work.
Thanks!

Comment: "Also, I am not sure if the data is getting stored in the database at all."  wouldn't it be reasonable to first check if there is any data? Also, I'm not sure that it is a good place for {% load %} tag inside template blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `add_staff_save` view, you are not creating not updating any staffs:

```py
# This creates a user
user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, user_type=2)

# This sets the related staffs' phone but does not save it
user.staffs.phone = phone

# This saves only the user, not the related FK. So the staffs is not updated, you'd need user.staffs.save() to update the staffs instance
user.save()
```

You explicitly need to:

- Create your user
- Then create a staff linked to your user

```py
user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email = email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, user_type=2)
# Assuming staffs does not exist yet:
staffs = Staffs.objects.create(admin =user, phone=phone)
# If it already exists, then just
user.staffs.phone = phone
user.staffs.save()
```